# shell script cut from variables

Tags: bash, shell, shellcode

The file is like this

```
aaa&123
bbb&234
ccc&345
aaa&456
aaa$567
bbb&678
```

I want to output:(contain "aaa" and text after &)

```
123
456
```

I want to do in in shell script,
Follow code be consider

```
#!/bin/bash
raw=$(grep 'aaa' 1.txt)
var=$(cut -f2 -d"&" "$raw")
echo $var
```

It give me a error like

```
cut: aaa&123
aaa&456
aaa$567: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it? and how to cut (or grep or other) from exist variables?

Many thanks!

Comment: ignore  "aaa$567" in the text file. I type it wrong(or it should be aaa&567)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP 'aaa&\K.*' file
```

Output:

```
123
456
```

---

`\K`: ignore everything before pattern matching and ignore pattern itself

From man grep:

```
-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.

-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)
```

Comment: It works, do you know why my code doesn't work, and how to cut grep from exist variables in shell script? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `raw="$(grep 'aaa&' 1.txt)"; var="$(cut -f2 -d"&" <<< "$raw")"; echo "$var"` or shorter:  `var=$(grep 'aaa&' 1.txt | cut -f2 -d"&"); echo "$var"`

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus has my vote. An awk alternative if GNU grep is not available:

```
awk -F'&' 'NF==2 && $1 ~ /aaa/ {print $2}' file
```

Using `&` as the field separator, for lines with 2 fields (i.e. `&` must be present) and the first field contains "aaa", print the 2nd field.

---

The error with your answer is that you are treating the grep output like a filename in the cut command.  What you want is this:

```
grep 'aaa.*&' file | cut -d'&' -f2
```

The pattern means "aaa appears before an &"